# Generic typing a function that is a prop to a component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What could be the correct way to pass a generic type in a function argument which is one of the prop of the Componenet.

I have tried something like this:

```
type Props = {
   children?: JSX.Element;
   onChange?: <T>(a: T, b: number) => void;
}
```

and using it like (which is giving ts error):

```js
...
handleChange = (a: SomeType[], b: number) => {
   return 1;
}
...
<Component onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the function argument `a` of `onChange` callback to be one of the values in `Props`, there is no need to use Generics. `onChange` does not return anything, `Component` invokes it with one of the possible prop values.

```
type Props = {
  children?: JSX.Element;
  myProp: SomeType[];
  onChange?: (
    // exclude here the prop value of children and the callback itself
    // effectively being a: SomeType[]
    a: Props[Exclude<keyof Props, "children" | "onChange">],
    b: number
  ) => void;
};

const Component = (props: Props) => <div>Hello{props.children}</div>;

// declare concrete prop value as example
declare let myProp: SomeType[];

const App = () => {
  const handleChange: Props["onChange"] = (a, b) => {
    return 1;
  };

  return (
    <Component myProp={myProp} onChange={handleChange} />
  );
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcARFDvmQNwBQokscA3nJQHYAmWUcAvnCIlylPDAC0XErTp0YATzBY4AZRJYAKkpUBeVkIgQAXHFQwowDgHMB9eTrgAFYmHT6WdOHFwALYAA2XJwA-KYAUqoAGgB0AKIBWCBYHDD03iAKLhBgpurJ2soA2gC66XAQHADCvsg2WGFwABRe3iim2W5FcQAeuAEArjwAPADWWAoQBM6uqAA05H6BwSlkcAA+5JU1ddZYZAB8JXOt3gBGphwDIGe8rQCUcLoHcABuEMBc9Pz2uJXmcCqJEgHBS8H0TTAsw6s0ezzgwy4wFeBwAElgAgEICwoTlUDElkFOPxhgB6JEo+yk0lwHj9ZCUOC4sBvZCDLDoGAQJlodBWOh0gIMlSJeCZTp5DSFLClX7-eAAQTALIhcJenm8fw4ANq3ESO3qT2ap3aMzx3T6gxG40m00680W-iJqw2W2qur2h2OJoucCuNzu3jVrBNlBgAygHDgAEZyj85N4wxGoy02gigeBKmC4OLXLoWLmcoJth6sPndVx9aXBKSDg9vvQgA)

If `Component`/`Props` them selves were generic and receive a type parameter from an outside component (not the case in your example), you could do it [like this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcARFDvmQNwBQokscA3nJQHYAmWUcAvnCIlylPDAC0XErTp0YATzBY4AZRJYAKkpUBeVkIgQAXHFQwowDgHMB9eTrgAFYmFQAeTQD44+lnTg4XAALYAAbLk4AflMAKVUADQA6AFEwrBAsDhh6QJAFFwgwU00AbQBdXLgIDgBhYOQbLBi4AAoAwJRTQrdPL1KUgA9cMIBXHncAaywFCAJnVw9vABpyEPDIrLI4AB9yGvrG6ywyL3LljsCAI1MOUZAr3g6ASl8fADcIYC56fntcGrmOC1EiQDhZeD6TxwLCDGBZLjoFj8LytMCLbqLPqvXQ+dqBdxcYDvLyXOAACSwYTCEDJLHRRVQSXWEU4-A67gA9ESSXRnvZFMo4ABBMBgHpLHx+DoEIwlCq-f6A+CisC+ODQ2Hw7hIlFojEisUS7FvVgdAEcIENbjpQ5NdX4zrITGMvoDYZjCbTWbzY0rNahVlbXb7OrW46nc5km5wO4PJ6BHE+fyddhYGCjKAcOAARiqfzkgUoGazGpB4BqELg+R6unpiySsogggO4awdetXFtbcEnK8iroQA).

Cheers, hope it helps